# How do I interpret this BASH statement in my script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am not very well-versed in Linux scripting using Bash, so I wanted to understand what the following line means:

```
 [ ! -z "$lastPID" -a -d /proc/$lastPID ] && exit
```

I realize if the statement is in the brackets is true, then the script exits. What I would like to do is something else, instead of exiting I would like to set a variable to 1.

can I just update the statement like this?

```
 [ ! -z "$lastPID" -a -d /proc/$lastPID ] && $prc=1
```

Comment: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=%5B+%21+-z+%22%24lastPID%22+-a+-d+%2Fproc%2F%24lastPID+%5D+%26%26+exit  `!` is negation. Also `$prc=1` is invalid, you can `prc=1`

Comment: Yes, except it would be `prc=1` without the `$`.

Comment: This is great!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, `! -z "$lastPID"` can be simplified to `-n "$lastPID"`. `-z` tests if a string is empty, `-n` tests if it's not empty.

Comment: Note that `-a` is marked obsolescent in [the POSIX `test` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (look for the `OB` markers), and should not be used in new code. The better way to write this is `[ "$lastPID" ] && [ -d "/proc/$lastPID" ] && exit` (`-z` is the inverse of `-n`; instead of `! -z`, better to just use `-n`; and `-n` is the *default* operation when `test` is given only one operation).

Answer (score -1):

I wish to publish the answer from @Kamil Cuk with reference to [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain)

[explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain) is an outstanding tool for reverse engineering and debugging.

[image]

Comment: I really don't advise using explainshell for debugging; it's frequently incomplete, when not outright inaccurate. http://shellcheck.net/ is much better suited to diagnosing poorly-behaved code (though it doesn't try to look into individual commands the way explainshell does).

Comment: I found it to be helpful in explaining my issue